# How to mantain old releases without creating long-lived branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, release-management

I have read

- The book "Pro Git : Maintaining a Project"
- Git : Documentation/howto/maintain-git.txt

How to mantain the old releases without creating a separate long-lived branches? In other words, I am interested how to work with a branch "maint" in a Git repository.

For example (merging with topic branches and the integration of contributors of patches are not shown, other branches of "next", "pu" is also not shown here).

These images can be viewed also [here](http://gist.github.com/185129).

```
          +--master
          |
          +--maint
          |
  (c1)->(c2)
          |
          +--tag : feature-release v1.0
```

Next time:

```
tag:feature-rel v1.0--+                   +--master
                      |                   |
              (c1)->(c2)->(c)->(c)->(c)->(c)
                      |
                      +->(c)->(c)->(c)
                                    |
                                    +--maint
                                    |
                                    +--tag:maint-rel v1.0.1
```

Next, as described in "maintain-git.txt", run :

```
 $ git checkout master
 $ git merge maint
```

Result:

```
tag:feature-rel v1.0--+                          +--master
                      |                          |
              (c1)->(c2)->(c)->(c)->(c)->(c)->(c100)
                      |                       /
                      +->(c)->(c)->(c50)-----'
                                    |
                                    +--maint
                                    |
                                    +--tag:maint-rel v1.0.1
```

Next time:

```
                               +--master
                               |
                               +--tag:feature-rel v2.0
                               |
   ...->(c)->(c100)->(c101)->(c102)
               /
 ...->(c50)---'
       |
       +--maint
       |
       +--tag:maint-rel v1.0.1
```

And at this point I have few questions:

1. What to do with the branch "maint" ? I understand pointer "maint" should be moved in the same position as the "master" ? How ?
2. Afterwards how then to make a fork of a branch "maint" from branch "master" ?
3. If appear a patch (elapse a very long time, for example, the current feature-release v10.0 ) for the old "tag:maint-rel v1.0.1", how to integrate it in the "maint" and in "master"?

Answer (score 2):

> how to mantain the old releases without creating a separate long-lived branches

Maintenance branches are often done per release, and long-lived, since they serve to fix bug specific to that release, and not everything need to be merged back into the current development.

> 1/ What to do with the branch "maint" ? I understand pointer "maint" should be moved in the same position as the "master" ? How ?

I am not sure why you would reuse maint here. a rebase would not work.
May be a

```
$ git checkout maint
$ git reset --merge c102
```

Since 'maint' was already merged into master, I guess this reset would not update any of the newer files in master.

I just tested it:

[alt text http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/4425/resetmerge.png](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/4425/resetmerge.png)

It does move the HEAD of 'maint', without touching any files in master.

> 2/ Afterwards how then to make a fork of a branch 'maint' from branch 'master' ?

Well the reset would have move the head of 'maint' to the current development: if C102 is the v2, all you need is to checkout 'maint', and you would fork right away.

That will give you:

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/91/resetmerge2.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/91/resetmerge2.png)

> 3/ if appear a patch (elapse a very long time, for example, the current feature-release v10.0 ) for the old "tag:maint-rel v1.0.1", how to integrate it in the "maint" and in "master"?

There you need to create a "named maintenance branch":

```
$ git checkout -b maint-1.0 c50
$ # work on patch
$ git checkout maint
$ git cherry-pick ... # only merge what you need in maint
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick ... # only merge what you need in maint
```

Note: you may want not merging the same thing in maint (which may still need some part of the fix done in maint-1.0) and master (which may have evolved so much that most of the patch is no longer relevant)